# CBV поиск в Django

Tags: python, django, django-template, django-view

Переписываю поиск в Джанго с FBV в CBV.

> FBV Search:

```
def searchbar(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    searched = request.POST["searched"]
    students = Student.objects.filter(Q(first_name__contains=searched) | Q(last_name__contains=searched))
    return render(request, template_name='tools/searchbar.html',
                  context={"searched": searched, "students": students})
```

> CBV Search

```
class StudentSearchView(ListView):
model = Student
template_name = "tools/searchbar.html"

def get_queryset(self):
    q = self.request.GET.get("q")
    object_list = Student.objects.filter(Q(first_name__icontains=q) | Q(last_name__icontains=q))
    return object_list
```

> searchbar.html

```
   {% extends "index.html" %}

    {% block content %}
          {% if q %}
              <h1>Search Results</h1>
           <br/>
              {% for student in object_list %}
                <li>
                  {{ student.first_name }} {{ student.last_name }}<br/>
               </li>
             {% endfor %}
         {% else %}
             <h1>Nothing to search</h1>
         {% endif %}
       {% endblock %}
```

> index.html

```
 <form class="form-inline" method="GET" action="{% url "searchbar" %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" name="q"
                       placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Никакой ошибки не возвращает, при поиске перекидывается в блок else (searchbar.html
) и пишет что "Nothing to search". В чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Очевидно в том, что внутри шаблона переменную `q` никто не создавал и она не существует

Comment: @andreymal это не она q = self.request.GET.get("q")?

Comment: Это локальная переменная внутри функции `get_queryset`, и она уничтожается сразу после завершения работы функции

Comment: @andreymal Ваш первый комментарий очень помог. На самом деле проблема была в том, что в searchbar.html необходимо было прописать {% if object_list %}, так как это специфика ListView.